# Android transfer the system camera and then display the pictures in the ImageView

Tags: android

I know that call system camera is

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction("android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA");   
startActivity(intent);
```

i want display the pictures in the ImageView,but i don't konw how to do it.
is there anybody can give me a sample code?

edit1：
i also need store

```
String strPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File path = new File(strPath);
  if(!path.exists())
  path.mkdirs();
  strFileName = "test.jpg";
  strFilePath = strPath + "/" + strFileName;

  File file = new File(strFilePath);
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri）;
```

i use the up code to store, but how to see in photographic time?that is preview.

Comment: Please give proper description of the question.

Comment: I think you have to use onActivityResult method after taking photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity, and then grab the result in onActivityResult. Something like this:

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

}